# Array inside an array based on range of key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that I need to split into an array of arrays.  I've seen a lot on grouping, splitting, sorting, etc...  but these all create separate arrays.  I need to keep the one array.

```
data = [
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026704,
      Open: 1
    },
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026556,
      Open: 47
    },
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026627,
      Open: 11
    },
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026627,
      Open: 33
    },
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026627,
      Open: 17
    },
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026627,
      Open: 2
    }
]
```

I need to create a new array that puts objects into a subarray based off the range of *Open* < 11, 11 - 29, 30+ using javascript.

```
newdata = [
    [{
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026704,
      Open: 1
    },
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026556,
      Open: 2
    }
]
[
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026627,
      Open: 11
    },
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026627,
      Open: 17
    }
]
[
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026627,
      Open: 33
    },
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026627,
      Open: 47
    }
]
]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Loop over the original array and put the items in new arrays based on `open`. Then concatenate the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your array of arrays:

```
var newData = [];
newData[0] = data.filter(item => item.Open <= 10);
newData[1] = data.filter(item => item.Open > 10 && item.Open < 30);
newData[2] = data.filter(item => item.Open >= 30);
```

Comment: And of course this can also be written as `const newData = [data.filter(({Open}) => Open <= 10), data.filter(({Open}) => Open > 10 && Open < 30), data.filter(({Open}) => Open >= 30)]`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026704,
      Open: 1
    },
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026556,
      Open: 47
    },
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026627,
      Open: 11
    },
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026627,
      Open: 33
    },
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026627,
      Open: 17
    },
    {
      CustAccount: 'FEN000',
      JobNumber: 1026627,
      Open: 2
    }
];

const lessThan11 = [];
const lessThan29 = [];
const gt30 = [];

for (let item of data) {
   if (item.Open < 11) {
     lessThan11.push(item);
   } else if (item.Open <= 29) {
     lessThan29.push(item);   
   } else {
      gt30.push(item);
   }
}

const result= [lessThan11, lessThan29, gt30];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you Christian!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all the items in data and based on open values of that item put it in different arrays. Lastly,combine them to get newdata

```
const arr1=[];
const arr2=[];
const arr3=[];

for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
 if(data[i]['Open']<11){
  arr1.push(data[i]);
 }
 else if(data[i]['Open']<30){
  arr2.push(data[i]);
 }
 else arr3.push(data[i]);
}

var newdata=[arr1,arr2,arr3];
```

Comment: Thank you!  I tried the loop through on my own, but didn't think of joining all the new arrays into one...   Ugh!  Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with three empty arrays inside first, then push to the desired inside array based on the value of `Open`

```js
data=[{CustAccount:"FEN000",JobNumber:1026704,Open:1},{CustAccount:"FEN000",JobNumber:1026556,Open:47},{CustAccount:"FEN000",JobNumber:1026627,Open:11},{CustAccount:"FEN000",JobNumber:1026627,Open:33},{CustAccount:"FEN000",JobNumber:1026627,Open:17},{CustAccount:"FEN000",JobNumber:1026627,Open:2}]

const newdata = [[],[],[]]
data.map(el =>
{
  if(el.Open < 11)
  {
    return newdata[0].push(el)
  }
  else if(el.Open < 30)
  {
    return newdata[1].push(el)
  }
  else
  {
    return newdata[2].push(el)
  }
})

console.log(newdata)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we write a generic function to split an array according to which test the values pass, then we might write a function to do what you would like in this manner:

```js
const myGroups = splitInto ([
  ({Open}) => Open < 11,
  ({Open}) => Open < 30,
  ({Open}) => Open >= 30,
])
```

and then just call it with `myGroups (data)`.

You can see one implementation of that idea here:

```js
const splitInto = (fns) => (xs) =>
  xs .reduce (
    (rss, x) => {
      const idx = fns .findIndex (fn => fn (x))
      if (idx >= 0 && idx < fns.length) {rss [idx] .push (x)}
      return rss
    },
    Array.from(fns, () => [])
  )

const myGroups = splitInto ([
  ({Open}) => Open < 11,
  ({Open}) => Open < 30,
  ({Open}) => Open >= 30,
]) 

const data = [{CustAccount: 'FEN000', JobNumber: 1026704, Open: 1}, {CustAccount: 'FEN000', JobNumber: 1026556, Open: 47}, {CustAccount: 'FEN000', JobNumber: 1026627, Open: 11}, {CustAccount: 'FEN000', JobNumber: 1026627, Open: 33}, {CustAccount: 'FEN000', JobNumber: 1026627, Open: 17}, {CustAccount: 'FEN000', JobNumber: 1026627, Open: 2}]

console .log (myGroups (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that if none of the tests pass, the value is skipped altogether.  It would not be difficult to decide to add them to a dedicated final group or to throw an error.